# Google Web Starter Kit - JShint gives error with new Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm working with the Web Starter Kit and so far i find it very nice. I have however an issue that i can't really fix.

Whenever i create a new .JS file, the Gulp command will start spitting errors at me.

For intance this:

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

  function logThis() {
    console.log("Hello!");
  }

  logThis();
})();
```

Will result in this:

```
    JSHint failed for: D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\app\scripts\animations.js
[14:27:20] 'default' errored after 5.91 s
[14:27:20] Error: [object Object]
    at formatError (C:\Users\Bart\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bart\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:195:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
    at finish (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:53:5)
    at Gulp.onError (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:60:4)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:52:4)
    at DestroyableTransform.f (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\node_modules\end-of-stream\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.flush (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp-jshint\src\reporters\fail.js:41:14)
    at DestroyableTransform._flush (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp-jshint\src\stream.js:41:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp-jshint\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:135:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.g (events.js:199:16)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at finishMaybe (D:\Work & Resources\Projects\portfolio\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\portfolio\node_modules\gulp-jshint\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:371:12)
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You probably should create 2 separated questions.

Comment: Can you paste the text of that error rather than a screenshot - firstly it's hard to read, secondly it will help with the searchability of the question.

Comment: Thanks, i removed the second question and pasted the error instead of the screenshot.

Comment: The character "&" in your directory name looks way evil...

Comment: Hmm that could be, but it works just fine if i remove the new JS file. Everything renders, compiles and works.

Comment: I can see one valid error which jshint usually gives for IIFE, that IIFE should be a function call as a expression rather than function itself as a expression. What it means is change `(function(){ .... })()` to ` (function(){ .... }())`

Comment: That actually fixed it! Well, that and one crucial line that i didn't see untill scrolling upwards in the console. It stated "line 6  col 25  Strings must use singlequote." 

It works perfectly right now! Sometimes things can be so easy :) Thanks and happy new year!